# CSS: how to partially fill a star with color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to pass a rating value (for example `0.27`) from JS, turn it in to a percentage and fill a star with the class of `.half-star` with color partially (to that percentage amount).

The JavaScript code works properly in the console, and works with the rating value of `4.27` (as an example, properly all the first 4 stars get the class of `full-star` and the last one gets the class of `half-star` shown in the dev tool).

There are two issues here: First, no star with the class of `.half-star` is shown on the browser. Second, I want the star itself to be colored not the background of the star.

As the JavaScript is working properly, I just know that the issue is with the CSS code. But the information I found didn't exactly help me address the problem. How can I fix these two issues?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```js
const ratingValue = 4.27;
const percentageFilled = ratingValue - Math.floor(ratingValue);
const halfStarElement = document.querySelector(".half-star");

halfStarElement.style.width = percentageFilled * 100 + "%";
```

```css
/* To fill a ".half-star" star partially */

 :root {
  --half-star-percentage: percentageFilled * 100%;
}

.stars-landing i.half-star {
  clip-path: path("M10 0 L20 10 L10 20 Z")
  polygon(
  0 0,
  100% 0,
  100% calc(100% - var(--half-star-percentage)),
  calc(var(--half-star-percentage)) calc(100% - var(--half-star-percentage)),
  0 calc(100% - var(--half-star-percentage))
);
}
```

```html
<div class="stars-landing" id="stars-box">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star" data-star></i>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to use clip masking

Comment: As @DeanVanGreunen mentioned, you could use the star as a mask to cut a rectangle; by adjusting the rectangle's height, you can make it so only part of the background is filled. Another option would be to play around with linear gradient, that is, using a gradient that start solid, then abruptly becomes fully transparent.

Comment: Thanks @DeanVanGreunen for the idea of clip masking.
I edited the CSS code accordingly. Now, the fifth star is shown (I guess it was for the property of the pseudo-element set to absolute that was hidden) but the star itself is not yet filled with color. Did I write it incorrectly?

Comment: @shimamasaeli see my answer on this post... its a bit glitchy but you can improve on my solution

Comment: Thanks @Haroldo_OK
The problem with idea of linear gradient is that the background color of the star changes, not the color of the star itself (If I got you correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a working example. you will only need to update the div to have the correct variable css. such as `--rating: 2.5` in the style of the div.

you can also use javascript to update the `--rating` varable of the div

```css
:root {
  --star-size: 60px;
  --star-color: #fff;
  --star-background: #fc0;
}

.stars-landing {
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: var(--star-size);
  font-family: Times;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align:left;
  letter-spacing:-8px;
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
}

.stars-landing::before {
  content: '★★★★★';
  letter-spacing:-8px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) 0%, var(--star-background) var(--percent), rgba(0,0,0,1) var(--percent), rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transform: translatey(60px);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Times;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars-landing" id="stars-box" style="--rating: 2.6;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 2.3 out of 5.">★★★★★</div>
```

You may want to test further and also improve upon this solution

Comment: I think the problem here is that you can’t use the fontawesome icons natively

Comment: @DarkIntaqt yeah, is the best i could come up with at the moment